# Add sequence lengths to headers in a fasta file

Tags: bash, fasta

I have a multifasta file and would like to add the sequence lengths to the headers by keeping the sequences.

```
>Seq1
MADKLTRIAIVNHDKCKPKKCRQECKKSCPVVRMGKLCIEVTPQSKIAWISETLCIGCGI
KILAGKQKPNLGKYDDPPDWQEILTYFRGSELQNYFTKILEDDLKAIIKPQYVDQIPKAA
KGTVGSILDRKDETKTQAIVCQQLDLTHLKERNVEDLSGGELQRFACAVVCIQK

>Seq2
MADKLTRIAIVNHDKCKPKKCRQECKKSCPVVRMGKLCIEVTSQSKIAWISETLCIGCGI
CIKKCPFGALSIVNLPSNLEKETTHRYCANAFKLHRLPIPRPGEVLGLVGTNGIGKSTAL
KGTVGSILDRKDETKTQTVVCQQLDLTHLKERNVEDLSGGELQRFACAVVCIQKADIFMF
DEPSSYLDVKQRLKAAITIRSLINPDRYIIV
```

My desired output

```
>Seq1_174
MADKLTRIAIVNHDKCKPKKCRQECKKSCPVVRMGKLCIEVTPQSKIAWISETLCIGCGI
KILAGKQKPNLGKYDDPPDWQEILTYFRGSELQNYFTKILEDDLKAIIKPQYVDQIPKAA
KGTVGSILDRKDETKTQAIVCQQLDLTHLKERNVEDLSGGELQRFACAVVCIQK

>Seq2_211
MADKLTRIAIVNHDKCKPKKCRQECKKSCPVVRMGKLCIEVTSQSKIAWISETLCIGCGI
CIKKCPFGALSIVNLPSNLEKETTHRYCANAFKLHRLPIPRPGEVLGLVGTNGIGKSTAL
KGTVGSILDRKDETKTQTVVCQQLDLTHLKERNVEDLSGGELQRFACAVVCIQKADIFMF
DEPSSYLDVKQRLKAAITIRSLINPDRYIIV
```

I tried to use this command

```
awk '/^>/{if (l!="") print l; print; l=0; next}{l+=length($0)}END{print l}' file.fasta | paste - - | sed 's/\t/_/' | >seq_len.fasta
```

but it only shows the length without the sequence. 
Can you help me to fix that without using biopython or seqkit?
for example:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the line doesn't begin with `>`, accumulate the sequence data in a variable and add its length to a total variable. When the line begins with `>`, print the sequence that you were accumulating, and save the current line as the name of the next sequence. Finally, at the end of the file print the last sequence.

```
awk '/^>/ { if (name) {printf("%s_%d\n%s", name, len, seq)} name=$0; seq=""; len = 0; next}
    NF > 0 {seq = seq $0 "\n"; len += length()}
    END { if (name) {printf("%s_%d\n%s", name, len, seq)} }' file.fasta > seq_len.fasta
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but first i have linearised my file to avoid printing the length of each line.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the sequences were spread over multiple lines, I thought you just wrapped them in the question. I'll fix.